# NiFi Lookup Service Error - Failed to Lookup Coordinates in Lookup Service

Tags: apache-nifi

We keep getting this error when trying to use any Lookup Service (NiFi or 3rd party) to append additional attributes to our initial DB2 Query:

```
 Failed to lookup coordinates {LEGAL_ENTITY_ID_NUM=13366} in Lookup Service
```

Has anyone had any success merging data from 2 different sql queries based on a common Unique ID from both queries?   We've tried LookupRecord which uses Lookup Service, MergeRecord, and MergeContent - nothing seems to work??

Bottom line is - we have an initial main query (ID & Status) - then want to append an additional attribute (Name) from a 2nd query (just contains ID & Name) - onto each record of the main query - after joining on ID.

Whenever we try using LookupRecord, and pass the ID as a parameter via ? marks, we keep getting the above error.  We've gotten nowhere with MergeRecord too.  We have learned how to MergeContent, but that is not really what we want (is just a workaround).

Comment: When you use LookupRecord, what LookupService are you using? There currently is not a released implementation of a LookupService that works against a relatonial DB, although there is active work to implement one.

Comment: we didn't have any luck with the Lookup Service from NiFi, so we tried using a custom one built by a Chris Parker that one of our developers found, but no luck.  That one was named SQLRecordLookupService, and we tried emailing Chris Parker, but no reply.

Comment: We also tried MergeRecord Processor from NiFi, but no luck.

Comment: We also got MergeContent to work, with an error:  when it merges the output content from 2 separate queries, it doesn't append them properly.  It does append the results of one ExecuteSQL query with another ExecuteSQL query, after converting AvroToJSON, but it appends as 2 separate blocks of JSON text like follows:  [Qry1Field1,Qry1Field2][Qry2Field1,Qry2Field2].   This is not proper JSON format. It shouldn't have a "][" seperator between qry results.

Comment: MergeContent is meant to merge bytes of a flow file one after another, it has no idea that the content is JSON, so that is actually behaving as expected. MergeRecord understands records and can merge them together as proper JSON. In both cases though, merging is not joining, merging is writing content or records one after another to create larger flow files.

Comment: We have needed the DB lookup for a long time, and there is a pull request by one of the committers that was just submitted, so hopefully it will be available soon - https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/3341

Comment: can't wait for that!  any idea how soon?  can we get a work-in-process version?

Comment: You are free to do whatever you want with the code in that PR, you can build and use it, the Apache NiFi project can't provide a built version of it until its part of the standard release process